# Automatically indexing by a field name as desc

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

i have index type of book story that every week wants to put some books.

in this index i want to have always query by sorting a field name(in this case is "price" ) as desc so it's have some overhead on ES (cause of data volume)

in this service we always shows to user books by maximum to minimum price 
is possible to have this feature automatically or manually for sorting document of book type in index always by price as desc and then when to want to query them it's always sorted by price as desc and dont need to give it by:

```
"sort" : { "price" { "order" : "desc" } }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not keep your data ordered based on a field. Elasticsearch keeps the data as Lucene segments inside. Take a look here to better understand internal structure of ES: https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-from-the-bottom-up